# Running a combn function on different columns of a dataframe, one row at a time

Tags: r, magrittr, combn

I have the following data frame :

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  index number_1 number_2 number_3
  <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1     1 32       16       29      
2     2 13       50       47      
3     3 37       19       18
```

I would like to run a `combn` function with an parameter of 2 to every line of that tibble between the 3 columns `number`; that would yield a result along the lines of :

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  index combn
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 32,16
2     1 32,29
3     1 16,29
4     2 13,50
.............
```

---

I have thought of something like

```
theTibble %>%
               (
               select(., number_1 : nulber_3) %>% lapply(FUN = combn,2)
               ) %>% View
```

but to no avail.

I would like a pipe friendly solution.
What a possible solution would be?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in long format, for each `index` apply `combn` function selecting 2 values at a time, paste them into comma-separated string (`toString`) and `unnest`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -index) %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  summarise(combn = list(combn(value, 2, toString))) %>%
  unnest(combn)

#  index combn 
#  <int> <chr> 
#1     1 32, 16
#2     1 32, 29
#3     1 16, 29
#4     2 13, 50
#5     2 13, 47
#6     2 50, 47
#7     3 37, 19
#8     3 37, 18
#9     3 19, 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `pmap` to loop over the 'number' columns in each row, get the `combn` by selecting 2 elements, `paste` them together with `str_c` or `paste` and `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    transmute(index, Combn = pmap(select(., starts_with('number')), ~ 
            combn(c(...), 2, str_c, collapse ="," )))  %>%
    unnest(c(Combn))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
#  index Combn
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 32,16
#2     1 32,29
#3     1 16,29
#4     2 13,50
#5     2 13,47
#6     2 50,47
#7     3 37,19
#8     3 37,18
#9     3 19,18
```

---

Or with `gather`

```
df1 %>%
   gather(key, val, -index) %>% 
   group_by(index) %>%
   summarise(combn = list(combn(val, 2, toString))) %>%
   unnest(combn)
```

---

Or using `base R` with `apply`

```
lst1 <- apply(df1[-1], 1, combn, 2, paste, collapse=",", simplify = FALSE)
data.frame(index = rep(df1$index, lengths(lst1)), Combn = unlist(lst1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(index = 1:3, number_1 = as.character(c(32, 13, 37)),
   number_2 = as.character(c(16, 50, 19)), number_3 = as.character(c(29, 47, 18)))
```